# Shading of drools libraries leads to changes in text in GeneratorHelper.java class

Tags: java, maven, drools, maven-shade-plugin

I have the following set of dependencies in my pom.xml file

```
start of pom file
.
.
.
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>knowledge-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
.
.
.
end of pom file
```

I am using `maven-shade-plugin` to create the shaded dependency of this library.

Relocations being:

```
start of pom file
.
.
.
<relocation>
  <pattern>org</pattern>
    <shadedPattern>**shaded.pattern**.org</shadedPattern>
</relocation>
.
.
.
end of pom file.
```

When I did that, [this line](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/6.3.0.Final/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/rule/builder/dialect/asm/GeneratorHelper.java#L173) is getting replaced as

`invokeStatic(MethodComparator.class, "**shaded.pattern**.compareBytecode", Boolean.TYPE, List.class, List.class);`

because of which, it's causing issues.

Any idea why this string is being `relocated`? Any help on this is appreciated.

I have tried using the transformer specified in https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.23.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_building_and_running_drools_in_a_fat_jar, but it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to find information about `<build><plugins/></build>` into pom.xml. It was helpful for me when i try to add my local dependencies into m2 repository. If you also got a problem, i will help you soon.